# Тире или двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Допустимо ли в этом предложении тире? Знаю, что по правилам лучше двоеточие, но все же - допустимо ли?

Всё более значительное место занимает в нашем бизнесе инжиниринг – мы разрабатываем для заказчиков рабочие чертежи изделий, выдаём рекомендации по условиям сборки соединений, совместно с заказчиком осуществляем модернизацию оборудования.

Также и в этих предложениях:

Мы ценим превыше всего людей: наших работников, наших акционеров и партнёров, наших заказчиков.

Однако для его полноценной реализации нужны совершенно новые институционные условия: наша экономическая система не стимулирует развитие реальной конкуренции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае корректно всё-таки двоеточие (раскрытие сод., пояснение в БСП), тире будет авторским знаком, но оно возможно как разделение предложения на две части. На экзамене поставят ошибку, помимо него при нестрогом отношении возможно.

Во втором корректно тире как обособление однородных приложений в конце предложения. Мы ценим превыше всего людей -  наших работников, наших акционеров и партнёров, наших заказчиков.

Однако для его полноценной реализации нужны совершенно новые институционные условия: наша экономическая система не стимулирует развитие реальной конкуренции. - корректно двоеточие в БСП, где 2 часть - причина.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача имеет одно общее решение: мы можем заменить классическое двоеточие тире, но  в этом случае пояснительным отношениям придается дополнительное присоединительное значение. 
В каждом конкретном случае автор должен решить обоснованность такой замены.

В предложении (1) пояснительное значение, скорее всего, является  не добавочным, а основным, поэтому надо поставить двоеточие. В предложениях (2) и (3) возможны оба варианта.

В любом случае все эти решения должны корректироваться ПО ТЕКСТУ. Если тема предложения в тексте раскрывается подробно, то уместно двоеточие. Если она только упоминается, а текст рассказывает о более общих проблемах, то ставится присоединительное тире.

Свой выбор можно проверить интонацией: в случае двоеточия делается неполное понижение голоса перед увеличенной предупредительной паузой.

Comment: Большое спасибо.